# Creating styles-v21.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, resources, android-styles

In Android Studio, I imported a project which did not include `styles.xml (v21)`.
So I created a `styles-v21.xml` file in the `values` directory. Both `styles.xml` and `styles-v21.xml` are in the `values` directory now.

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    </style>

</resources>
```

styles-v21.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">

    </style>

</resources>
```

When I build the project I get a build error:

> Error:Error: Duplicate resources: C:\xxx\main\res\values\styles-v21.xml:style/AppTheme, C:\xxx\main\res\values\styles.xml:style/AppTheme

The error is that both resource files have the same `style` name: `AppTheme`. 
But in other projects and tutorials I've seen, these `styles` have the same name. One is for Android with version 21 compatibility and the other is for Android without the compatibility.

I guess I want to know if I should simply change the name or if these files are supposed to have the same name - which means there is a bigger problem at hand. How should I proceed?

Comment: Some places in your question, you refer to a `styles-v21` folder. Some places in your question, you refer to a `styles-v21` or `styles-v21.xml` file. Did you create all of these? If not, please edit your question to **accurately** explain what files you created where. The right answer, BTW, is to have a `res/values-v21/styles.xml` file.

Comment: *Fixed* - Ah I will do that and see if it works.

Comment: You don't need to maintain different styles.xml files to make your app compatible with all api levels. You can do that in a single styles.xml(default) file. Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53445541/5745574

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Right click on res folder, choose **New** --> **Android resource file**, set the same name for the new file "styles", in **Available qualifiers:** choose the last item "**Version**" and finally set "**Platform API level**" 21.

Answer (score 10):

By default, Android Studio doesn't create **styles.xml (v21)**. What you need to do is create a folder structure like the following:

- res/values/styles.xml
- res/values-v21/styles.xml

And this is what you will get in Android Studio:

[image]

Then you can defined different `AppTheme` for different API levels.

Comment: Can I delete the general styles.xml if I'm only targeting 21+?

Comment: @pfdint You don't have to keep the `res/values-v21/styles.xml` if you only target 21+. You can keep the generic one.

Answer (score 2):

You should create styles.xml for version 21 in values-v21 folder and android studio automatically add it as styles.xml(v21)

Answer (score 0):

correction to styles-v21.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent=""AppTheme.Base"">

    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a value folder with values-v21 caption. and create style.xml file in this with the same name as values folder like styles.xml. Now rebuild your project.