# Android statusbar icons color

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-styles, android-statusbar

I was wondering if it's possible to change the statusbar **icons** colour (**not** the statusbar colour, `colorPrimaryDark`)
[image]
Let's say I want this statusbar with:
`<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</item>`

and the icons in black, is it possible?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

> New in the M developer preview: windowLightStatusBar. Flipping this on
>   in your theme tells the system to use a dark foreground, useful for
>   lighter colored status bars. Note the M preview seems to have a bug
>   where notification icons remain white, while system status icons
>   correctly change to semitransparent black.

from: **Roman Nurik** Google+ [post](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/4WBSonAZxt1)
[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Not since Lollipop. Starting with Android 5.0, the guidelines say:

> Notification icons must be entirely white.

Even if they're not, the system will only consider the alpha channel of your icon, rendering them white

#### Workaround

The only way to have a coloured icon on Lollipop is to lower your `targetSdkVersion` to values `<21`, but I think you would do better to follow the guidelines and use white icons only.

If you still however decide you want colored icons, you could use the [DrawableCompat.setTint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html) method from the new v4 support library.

Comment: I did some google search and I couldn't find a proper way to this but If Android guidelines say that icons must be white, white it is :) Thanks!

Comment: There's got to be a better workaround for this. Several commercial apps out there are using colors. This is a horribly idiotic design move by Google. What were they thinking again, if at all?

Comment: If you look at Google's news app they do not have white status bar icons: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.magazines&hl=en_US

Comment: `<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>` worked for me.

Comment: I wonder why the Gmail App (as released in 2019-04) colors the status bar white and the icons/text dark-grey.

Comment: @DanielF A lot of apps that are mostly white/light use the `windowLightStatusBar` style, for example Gmail, Google Photos, Pinterest, Instagram and more

Comment: "Notification icons must be entirely white." that's funny tho, Google News is using gray color. Why would they set standards if they don't follow them?!

Comment: How would one use the DrawableCompat.setTint method on the status bar icons? I am not sure how to access the actual drawables o.O

Answer (score 269):

Yes it's possible to change it to gray (no custom colors) but this only works from API 23 and above you only need to add this in your values-v23/styles.xml

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

[image]

Comment: but its menu items icons color is still white how to change its menu item icons color to black?

Answer (score 132):

@eOnOe has answered how we can change status bar tint through xml. But we can also change it dynamically in code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    View decor = getWindow().getDecorView();
    if (shouldChangeStatusBarTintToDark) {
        decor.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
    } else {
        // We want to change tint color to white again.
        // You can also record the flags in advance so that you can turn UI back completely if
        // you have set other flags before, such as translucent or full screen.
        decor.setSystemUiVisibility(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! It was really suitable for my application because I didn't have to change the SDK version.

Comment: it is more correct: decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(decorView.getSystemUiVisibility() | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);

Comment: This is the best solution, also works on MI phones. You're a savior!

Comment: what is ShouldChangeStatusBarTintDark please??

Comment: Is there a constant value for zero e.g View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_DARK_STATUS_BAR

Answer (score 54):

if you have API level smaller than 23 than you must use it this way.
it worked for me declare this under **v21/style**.

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark" tools:targetApi="23">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="23">true</item>
```

Comment: You mean 23. :(

Comment: No I meant v21/Style if you don't know about that than please visit this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465064/creating-styles-v21-xml

Comment: Even if placed in a styles.xml with v21 qualifier this only works on devices running api 23 and above. In fact AS Lint highlights these items with a warning saying it will be ignored on android versions that doesn't support it. The `tools:targetApi="23"` part tells Lint to suppress this warning.

Answer (score 14):

***SystemUiVisibility*** flags are deprecated. Use ***WindowInsetsController*** instead

the code below sets the color of icons to black (for the light statusbar)

```java
//icon color -> black  
activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowInsetsController().setSystemBarsAppearance(APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS, APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS);
```

and the code below clears it(i.e. turns icon color to white for dark statusbar):

```java
//icon color -> white
activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowInsetsController().setSystemBarsAppearance(0, APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS);
```

link to docs :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsetsController#setSystemBarsAppearance(int,%20int)

Comment: how can i change the top codes for lower APIs

Comment: If it doesn't work remove "android:windowLightStatusBar" from theme's style

Comment: This code is not compiling. It says "Unresolved reference: getWindowInsetsController"

Comment: @LeonardoSibela can you provide the compelete line of code

Comment: @MarkAndrew thanks for replying, but sadly, I cannot. I solved this problem a while back and I don't remember what was going on. But I do appreciate that you replied. Have a good life bro :)

Answer (score 7):

You can do it **programmatically** with **retaining all other system UI visibility flags**.

```java
public static void changeStatusBarContrastStyle(Window window, Boolean lightIcons) {
     View decorView = window.getDecorView();
     if (lightIcons) {
         // Draw light icons on a dark background color
         decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(decorView.getSystemUiVisibility() & ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
     } else {
         // Draw dark icons on a light background color
         decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(decorView.getSystemUiVisibility() | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks mahmoud, Been looking for this from long time. other solutions needed changes to the theme and style which caused problems in the current screens design . this solution has no side effects .

Answer (score 5):

Setting `windowLightStatusBar` to `true` not works with Mi phones, some Meizu phones, Blackview phones, WileyFox etc.
I've found [such hack](https://github.com/chenglei1986/StatusBarColorManager/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/chenglei1986/statusbar/StatusBarUtil.java#L3) for Mi and Meizu devices. This is not a comprehensive  solution of this perfomance problem, but maybe it would be useful to somebody.

And I think, it would be better to tell your customer that coloring status bar (for example) white - is not a good idea. instead of using different hacks it would be better to define appropriate `colorPrimaryDark` according to the guidelines

Answer (score 2):

in kotlin you can use following lines

```
    val window = this.window
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
    window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white)
    WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView).apply {
        isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I used two line of code for different status bar color

**1st:** If status bar color is white then use this line of code to visible the status bar icon:

```
  pingAct.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
```

**2nd:** If you use dark color then use this line of code to make visible the status bar icon:

```
 pingAct.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for all those who want to change their **application's Notification small icon color** can use this `setColor` method of `NotificationCompat.Builder`

Example:

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "whatever_channel_id")
        **.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification) //set icon for notification**
        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.pink))
        .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
        .setContentText("Notification Message!")
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can change it. but in api 22 and above, using NotificationCompat.Builder and setColorized(true) :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, context.getPackageName())
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(icon, level)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setContentIntent(intent)
                .setColorized(true)
                .setDefaults(0)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

Comment: Are you sure? The documentation says "When set, the color set with setColor(int) will be used as the background color of this notification." and "For most styles, the coloring will only be applied if the notification is for a foreground service notification." It does not seem to be possible to change the foreground color of the icon.

Comment: This is for foreground notifications only and only applies to the notification item - not the notification icon.