# Deciding which background colour to use for status bar

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

As I have specified a hex value for the background colour of my action bar, I'm finding it a bit difficult deciding which hex value to use for the background colour of the status bar. Are there any tools out there that can help find a suitable background colour for the status bar when one specifies a background colour of the action bar?

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#E32017")));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set color on StatusBar as nearest of your ActionBar color:

```
private String actionBarColor = "#AC6363";
```

Set **Background color** on **ActionBar**:

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(actionBarColor)));
```

To set StatusBar color: on **onCreate** of **Activity**:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getFactorColor(Color.parseColor(actionBarColor), 0.8f));
}
```

Get **factor color**:

```
private int getFactorColor(int color, float factor) {
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
    hsv[2] *= factor;
    color = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
    return color;
}
```

**Done**

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Is it possible to change the status bar icons tint to a dark colour?

Comment: @MacaronLover, No dude, it's not possible as per guidelines. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075827/android-statusbar-icons-color for more info. Thanks.

Comment: @MacaronLover, you did set color on ActionBar but not on StatusBar.

Comment: @MacaronLover, No, Sorry. I will try my best and Let you know for the same

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only from Lollipop (API level 21) onwards.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#E32017"));
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to solve this with a proper answer and code?[Fast scroll large letter thumb preview not appearing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321784/fast-scroll-large-letter-thumb-preview-not-appearing)