# Google IO 2016 App's status bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, statusbar

How the change status bar icon's color change in like Google IO 2016 App? I know there is no method. It looks like inverted.

[image: Screenshot]

**EDIT**

I finally find from a [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075827/android-statusbar-icons-color), it can be only grey if you are api 23 or above using:

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [material theme](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) and change the colors to get the theme you want.

Answer (score 1):

well in your `values-v21/styles.xml` you can change the color and theme to whatever you want

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_secondary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/color_primary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Update:**

In Marshmallow you can achieve dark icons with light status bar with `android:windowLightStatusBar` attribute, e.g in your `values-v23/styles.xml` you can set

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Comment: this is for status bar color. not for status bar icon color.