# How to change android status bar color to white and status bar icon color to grey

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-view, statusbar

i am trying to change color of my status bar to white with grey icons. i have tried almost every code solution for this problem but non of them worked for me.

i am using this java fucntion to change it and i am also posting my style(21) code.

```
public static void statusBarColor(Window window, Context ctx) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                //Window window = getActivity().getWindow();

                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                window.setStatusBarColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.statusbar_color));
            }
        }
```

this is my java code but its not working after thousand tries.
and below is my style.xml (21)

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="23">true</item>   
    </style>
```

if you think its duplicate of some other question then i should let you now i have tried 3,4 pages of google search and also implemented them.

Comment: Whats does your xml do as of now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is achievable with this flag:

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Unfortunately it's available from API 23 upwards, so you have to specify it in `values-v23/styles.xml`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075827/android-statusbar-icons-color/30075921#30075921) for more info.

There is not any backport of this functionality, therefore it won't work on any lower 23 at the time of writing this.

[image]

Comment: yes but the question is that how to implement same thing in lollipop. its very confusing tight now

Comment: and upvote to question will also be highly appreciatable :)