# How to modify the status bar in android programming?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to set the color of status bar to white and icons such as wifi and battery to black. How can I do this?. I will prefer to do this via using `Theme.AppCompat`

Comment: Try to look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android

Comment: @leyreyyan I tried this by doing this  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/white</item> but I want to change the color of battery ,wifi etc icons into black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color of the status bar can be changed by :

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">your_required_color</item>
```

From API 21, to change color of status bar without using "colorPrimaryDark" use:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">your_required_color</item>
```

Since Lollipop. Starting with Android 5.0, the guidelines say:

Notification icons must be entirely white.

Even if they're not, the system will only consider the alpha channel of your icon, rendering them white

Refer this : [Android statusbar icons color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075827/android-statusbar-icons-color)

But from API 23, to change system status icons to semitransparent black you can use :

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Refer this : https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/4WBSonAZxt1

Answer (score 0):

You can change your statusBarColor by typing below attribute in your style.xml you need to input this code in your base theme.

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">COLOR THAT YOU WANT TO CHANGE</item>
```