# Status Bar Icon color does not change with Theme

Tags: android, notifications, drawable, statusbar, status

In Notification, I used drawable xml as a **setSmallIcon**. When Status Bar background changes to white then my white icon disappears (actually background color and icon become same color).
But if I use image icon as a **setSmallIcon** then status bar icon's color changes to grey.

**When Status Bar is white:**

[image]

**When Status Bar is non white:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_list,level);
```

**A portion of drawable file:**

```
<item android:maxLevel="86">
    <layer-list>
        <item
            android:bottom="@dimen/bottom_margin"
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_8"
            android:left="@dimen/ic_2_1_left"
            android:right="@dimen/ic_2_1_right"
            android:top="@dimen/upper_margin" />
        <item
            android:bottom="@dimen/bottom_margin"
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_6"
            android:left="@dimen/ic_2_2_left"
            android:right="@dimen/ic_2_2_right"
            android:top="@dimen/upper_margin" />
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item android:maxLevel="87">
    <layer-list>
        <item
            android:bottom="@dimen/bottom_margin"
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_8"
            android:left="@dimen/ic_2_1_left"
            android:right="@dimen/ic_2_1_right"
            android:top="@dimen/upper_margin" />
        <item
            android:bottom="@dimen/bottom_margin"
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_7"
            android:left="@dimen/ic_2_2_left"
            android:right="@dimen/ic_2_2_right"
            android:top="@dimen/upper_margin" />
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item android:maxLevel="88">
    <layer-list>
        <item
            android:bottom="@dimen/bottom_margin"
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_8"
            android:left="@dimen/ic_2_1_left"
            android:right="@dimen/ic_2_1_right"
            android:top="@dimen/upper_margin" />
        <item
            android:bottom="@dimen/bottom_margin"
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_8"
            android:left="@dimen/ic_2_2_left"
            android:right="@dimen/ic_2_2_right"
            android:top="@dimen/upper_margin" />
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

How can I change xml drawable icon color with status bar background(white)?

*Sorry for my bad english.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

After setting your drawable in your Activity write:

```
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(your_color_in_hex));
```

See if it works and update please.

Comment: Okay can you post your drawable please

Comment: Not working.
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window android.app.Activity.getWindow()' on a null object reference at com.example.myapp.service.DataService.onCreate(DataService.java:121).


Actually I want to change status bar icon color only status bar background become white

Comment: drawable is a long file. I added a portion.

Answer (score 0):

before the super.OnCreate() in your activity....

add the following line of code..

```
setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
```

Comment: Not working.
It's a notification and trigger from background in anytime.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android 5.0, the guidelines say:

> Notification icons must be white.

Even if they're not, the system will only consider the alpha channel of your icon, rendering them white.

Some  usefull links  :-

[Android statusbar icons color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075827/android-statusbar-icons-color)

[Notification bar icon turns white in Android 5 Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387602/notification-bar-icon-turns-white-in-android-5-lollipop)

Hope it helps.