# Ionic Android statusbar icons color

Tags: ionic-framework

Can I change the icons color by config.xml with Ionic?

Like this: [Android statusbar icons color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075827/android-statusbar-icons-color) but using ionic 4.

I'm using it to change the background color, but I don't know if it's possible to change the icons color by the config as well.

```
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#0c6263" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar/) I think this will be the answer

Comment: I wish to know if I can change by config.xml.

Comment: Oh I undestand. Thanks.

Comment: You should use native plugin in order to change color of status bar, if you change it using config.xml it might still change into default settings though I didnt try it peace

Comment: this `this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#2e3271");` only change background, how to change the icon color?

Comment: You cannot change icon color. You can use StatusBar.styleDefault (for dark / black icon) and StatusBar.styleLightContent (for light / white icons)