# How to change status bar color transparent and items on it to green in android?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I want to make the status bar like in the image below.

[image: how to change colors of my status bar according to this pic]

I tried a few things but none of them worked. Can some one point me to the right direction.

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow**, well your question shows lack of research here, and **`FYI`** StackOverflow is neither a forum, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can **[help with certain problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**, but it's your job to **[put some efforts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7666442)** in the first place, including elementary **[(re)search](https://www.google.co.in/)**. Read **[how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**

Comment: Agreed with @NileshRathod.Though check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075827/android-statusbar-icons-color

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android statusbar icons color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075827/android-statusbar-icons-color)

Comment: i tried some of the answers from the link but none of them worked

Comment: <style name="StatusBar" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light"  tools:targetApi="23">
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="23">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorWhite</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

and add this line to theme

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="23">true</item>
```

Comment: how to make it in api level 21 ?

Comment: i guess you cant change satus color in api21