# Color of status bar icons in Dialog's Window

Tags: android, android-statusbar, android-window

This is the code which I use for changing color of status bar icon:

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = if (light) {
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
} else {
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work for `Window` object of a `Dialog`. Any idea why?

EDIT: It is not a duplicate of [Android statusbar icons color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075827/android-statusbar-icons-color) - the link SO thread doesn't mention `Dialog`s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android statusbar icons color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075827/android-statusbar-icons-color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was executing this code from `DialogFragment.onStart` and I should call it from `onResume`

Answer (score -1):

Activity and child dialog of that activity share's same window. So if you set something on window inside dialog code it will still impact the window of that activity. If you are dealing with dialog title then its not status bar. Its title view of that dialog