# How do I change the colour of status bar icons when a fragment is opened?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have created 2 fragments and made them overlap using bottom sheet. First one fragment opens, then the second framgment opens, but when the 2nd fragment is closed,the colour of the status bar icons change to white if the status bar background is white and same for dark.

How do I fix this? Or how do I change the colour of status bar icons?

I have read the docs and read about WindowInsetsController but this will do it for android R only. My issue persists for all versions.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the icons with a specific color but with that in your `styles.xml` file you can make it light or dark. Keep in mind that it only works API 23 and above.

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

More references or ways of individual solutions you can find at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075827/android-statusbar-icons-color).

Comment: That means my minimum sdk should be 23 to work

Comment: Yes, exactly. Hope that helped. Cheers :)