# How to change the text statusbar color on API 29 or above

Tags: android, kotlin

i don't know how to change the text of the status bar on android API 29.
i want change the text and icon to black color.
How to fix it please?

i tried this, but i have an error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLWfw.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android statusbar icons color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075827/android-statusbar-icons-color)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATING MIN API FROM 21 TO 23**

you just need to go in your app's `build.gradle` file and change version like this:

```
android {
    ....
    
    defaultConfig {
         ...
         minSdk 23   // just replace minSdk 21 with minSdk 23 here
         ...
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Inside your `themes.xml` file in the `res -> values` , you should add these 2 attributes. This produces the following output on API level 30 for me. (Image below)

```
<resources>

<style>

    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>    

</style>

</resources>
```

[image]

**Old Answer:**

try this inside your `Activity's onCreate()` method and let me know if that works as expected for you :)

```
window.statusBarColor = resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
```

Comment: it does not work. Only the color of the STATUSBAR changes ...
What I want is for the color of the text to change

Comment: Okay then I'm editing my answer for that case :)

Comment: are you sure i have to put this code in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: oh sorry no, it has to be in the `themes` folder under the `values` folder, I'll edit again

Comment: thanks for your help but i have an error

Comment: you can check ly edit post.

Comment: Can you hover over it to see the error message? I had it placed at the exact same place as you do, but I didn't get any errors.

Comment: ok Mehul, you can now check my edit. Thanks.

Comment: the error means that this attribute isn't supported for API level 21, but it works for API 23 and up. So just need to update the minimum supported level to 23, editing my answer for this part.