# Android Material Dark Theme

Tags: android

Hello I am new to Android. How can I build a dark theme in Android where all background is black and primary text and input color is deep orange instead of white?

This is the current style for my app:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

The theme is dark with these settings but I am unable to set the primary text color to deep orange.  What do I need to add in this style so that all my white text and inputs have orange color?

**This is what kind of theme I need for my app:**
[image: Image of an Android phone with the theme I need]

Answer (score 0):

Create a another `style.xml` for `api` 21 using reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32336196/5539140) and write the below code in your new `style.xml`

```
<style name="MaterialStyle" parent="AppTheme.base">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
</style>
```

And also change your old `styles.xml` with below code,

```
<style name="MaterialStyle" parent="AppTheme.base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and also update in manifest.xml

```
android:theme="@style/MaterialStyle"
```